# Record Screen with Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, electron

Is there any way I can record My Electron App's Window? My monitor isn't 1080p so I have set that resolution in Dev Tools. I wanna record the window in 1080p Resolution, When I try to record using a screen recorder and only capture the window part. The quality that comes out is really bad. I would love if someone can tell me a solution!

[image]

And I mentioned Chrome in the Title because electron also uses Chrome!